# How sort recyclerview by data

Tags: android, sorting, android-recyclerview

I am trying to sort my recyclerview by Title, name, date and tag but it is giving me the

following error:-

```
06-04 08:55:24.560 18488-18488/com.package.name D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-04 08:55:24.560 18488-18488/com.package.name W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x5cd4ab20)
06-04 08:55:24.560 18488-18488/com.package.name I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 18488 SIG: 9
06-04 08:55:24.560 18488-18488/com.package.name D/AndroidRuntime: procName from cmdline: com.package.name
06-04 08:55:24.560 18488-18488/com.package.name E/AndroidRuntime: in writeCrashedAppName, pkgName :com.package.name
06-04 08:55:24.560 18488-18488/com.package.name D/AndroidRuntime: file written successfully with content: com.package.name StringBuffer : ;com.package.name
06-04 08:55:24.560 18488-18488/com.package.name E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                        Process: com.package.name, PID: 18488
                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                            at com.package.name.Formdir.FormMainFragment.onClick(FormMainFragment.java:142)
                                                                            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4499)
                                                                            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18571)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
                                                                            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-04 08:56:35.620 19212-19212/com.package.name I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getSystemService, referenced from method com.package.name.app.MyApplication.access$super
06-04 08:56:35.620 19212-19212/com.package.name W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 586: Landroid/content/Context;.getSystemService (Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
06-04 08:56:35.630 19212-19212/com.package.name D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0035
06-04 08:56:35.630 19212-19212/com.package.name I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method com.package.name.app.MyApplication.access$super
```

This is my main Fragment:-

```
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.ImageView;


import com.package.name.R;
import com.package.name.extras.SortListener;
import com.oguzdev.circularfloatingactionmenu.library.FloatingActionButton;
import com.oguzdev.circularfloatingactionmenu.library.FloatingActionMenu;
import com.oguzdev.circularfloatingactionmenu.library.SubActionButton;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class FormMainFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

public static TabLayout tabLayout;
public static ViewPager viewPager;
public static int int_form_main_items = 3;

//tag associated with the FAB menu button that sorts by name
private static final String TAG_SORT_NAME = "sortName";
//tag associated with the FAB menu button that sorts by date
private static final String TAG_SORT_DATE = "sortDate";
//tag associated with the FAB menu button that sorts by ratings
private static final String TAG_SORT_RATINGS = "sortRatings";
private FloatingActionButton mFAB;
private FloatingActionMenu mFABMenu;
private MyFormMainAdapter myFormMainAdapter;

public FormMainFragment() {
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    /**
     *Inflate tab_layout and setup Views.
     */
    View formMainView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.form_main_layout, null);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) formMainView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) formMainView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

    /**
     *Set an Apater for the View Pager
     */
    viewPager.setAdapter(new MyFormMainAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

    /**
     * Now , this is a workaround ,
     * The setupWithViewPager dose't works without the runnable .
     * Maybe a Support Library Bug .
     */

    tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }
    });


    //define the icon for the main floating action button
    ImageView iconFAB = new ImageView(getActivity());
    iconFAB.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_new);

    //set the appropriate background for the main floating action button along with its icon
    mFAB = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(getActivity())
            .setContentView(iconFAB)
            .setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.selector_button_red)
            .build();

    //define the icons for the sub action buttons
    ImageView iconSortName = new ImageView(this.getActivity());
    iconSortName.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_alphabets);
    ImageView iconSortDate = new ImageView(this.getActivity());
    iconSortDate.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_calendar);
    ImageView iconSortRatings = new ImageView(this.getActivity());
    iconSortRatings.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_important);

    //set the background for all the sub buttons
    SubActionButton.Builder itemBuilder = new SubActionButton.Builder(getActivity());
    itemBuilder.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.selector_sub_button_gray));


    //build the sub buttons
    SubActionButton buttonSortName = itemBuilder.setContentView(iconSortName).build();
    SubActionButton buttonSortDate = itemBuilder.setContentView(iconSortDate).build();
    SubActionButton buttonSortRatings = itemBuilder.setContentView(iconSortRatings).build();

    //to determine which button was clicked, set Tags on each button
    buttonSortName.setTag(TAG_SORT_NAME);
    buttonSortDate.setTag(TAG_SORT_DATE);
    buttonSortRatings.setTag(TAG_SORT_RATINGS);

    buttonSortName.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonSortDate.setOnClickListener(this);
    buttonSortRatings.setOnClickListener(this);

    //add the sub buttons to the main floating action button
    mFABMenu = new FloatingActionMenu.Builder(getActivity())
            .addSubActionView(buttonSortName)
            .addSubActionView(buttonSortDate)
            .addSubActionView(buttonSortRatings)
            .attachTo(mFAB)
            .build();

    return formMainView;

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    //call instantiate item since getItem may return null depending on whether the PagerAdapter is of type FragmentPagerAdapter or FragmentStatePagerAdapter
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment) myFormMainAdapter.instantiateItem(viewPager, viewPager.getCurrentItem());
    if (fragment instanceof SortListener) {

        if (v.getTag().equals(TAG_SORT_NAME)) {
            //call the sort by name method on any Fragment that implements sortlistener
            ((SortListener) fragment).onSortByName();
        }
        if (v.getTag().equals(TAG_SORT_DATE)) {
            //call the sort by date method on any Fragment that implements sortlistener
            ((SortListener) fragment).onSortByDate();
        }
        if (v.getTag().equals(TAG_SORT_RATINGS)) {
            //call the sort by ratings method on any Fragment that implements sortlistener
            ((SortListener) fragment).onSortByRating();
        }
    }

}

class MyFormMainAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MyFormMainAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }


    /**
     * Return fragment with respect to Position .
     */

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new FormFragment();
            case 1:
                return new AdmitFragment();
            case 2:
                return new ResultFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return int_form_main_items;

    }

    /**
     * This method returns the title of the tab according to the position.
     */

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "New Jobs";
            case 1:
                return "Admit Cards";
            case 2:
                return "Results";
        }
        return null;
    }


}


}
```

and this is form fragment:-

```
public class FormFragment extends Fragment implements FormsLoadedListener,SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener,SortListener,SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {


//The key used to store arraylist of movie objects to and from parcelable
private static final String STATE_FORM = "state_forms";
//the arraylist containing our list of box office his
private ArrayList<FormItem> mListForms = new ArrayList<>();
//the adapter responsible for displaying our movies within a RecyclerView
private AdapterForms mAdapter;

private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;
//the recyclerview containing showing all our movies
private RecyclerView mRecyclerForms;
//the TextView containing error messages generated by Volley
private TextView mTextError;
private FormSorter mSorter = new FormSorter() ;

//the sorter responsible for sorting our movie results based on choice made by the user in the FAB

// private MovieSorter mSorter = new MovieSorter();

public FormFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment FragmentBoxOffice.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static FormFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    FormFragment fragment = new FormFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    //put any extra arguments that you may want to supply to this fragment
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

public void onFormsLoaded() {

}




@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.form_layout,container,false);
    mTextError = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textVolleyError);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.swipeFormHits);
    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
    mRecyclerForms =(RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.listFormHits);
//set the layout manager before trying to display data
    mRecyclerForms.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    mAdapter = new AdapterForms(getActivity());
    mRecyclerForms.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    if (savedInstanceState != null){

        mListForms = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(STATE_FORM);
    } else {

        mListForms = MyApplication.getWritableDatabase().readForms(DBForms.FORMS);

        if (mListForms.isEmpty()){
            L.m("FormFragment: executing task from fragment");
            new TaskLoadForms(this).execute();
        }
    }

    mAdapter.setForms(mListForms);
    return layout;


}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

    outState.putParcelableArrayList(STATE_FORM, mListForms);
}

private void handleVolleyError(VolleyError error) {
    //if any error occurs in the network operations, show the TextView that contains the error message
    mTextError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if (error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
        mTextError.setText(R.string.error_timeout);

    } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
        mTextError.setText(R.string.error_auth_failure);
        //TODO
    } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
        mTextError.setText(R.string.error_auth_failure);
        //TODO
    } else if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
        mTextError.setText(R.string.error_network);
        //TODO
    } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
        mTextError.setText(R.string.error_parser);
        //TODO
    }
}


/**  * Called when the user chooses to sort results by name through the menu           displayed inside FAB
**/
@Override
public void onSortByName() {
    L.t(getActivity(),"sorted by nme");
   // mSorter.sortFormsByName(mListForms);
  //  mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

/**
 * Called when the user chooses to sort results by date through the menu          displayed inside FAB
**/
@Override
public void onSortByDate() {
  //  mSorter.sortFormsByDate(mListForms);
  //  mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onSortByRating() {

}

/**
 * Called when the user chooses to sort results by rating through the menu displayed inside FAB

@Override
public void onSortByRating() {
    mSorter.sortMoviesByRating(mListMovies);
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

/**
 * Called when the AsyncTask finishes load the list of movies from the web
 **/


@Override
public void onFormsLoaded(ArrayList<FormItem> listForms) {
            L.m("FormFRagment: Onformloaded fragment");
    if (mSwipeRefreshLayout.isRefreshing()){
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }
    mAdapter.setForms(listForms);
}

@Override
public void onRefresh() {
    L.m("onReFresh");
    new TaskLoadForms(this).execute();
```

i also want to  add a searchView filter so that i can search recyclerView data by title if anyone any one have a tutorial please comment a link
}

```
}
```

Comment: You have a null object at line 142 of FormMainFragment.java... Perhaps you can fix it yourself?

Comment: i am beginner can you tell me how please

Comment: If you are a beginner, you should probably read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors... That will get you through over half the errors you get

Comment: And here's the link for the code that you've copied from as a working reference  https://github.com/slidenerd/materialtest/blob/master/app/src/main/java/materialtest/vivz/slidenerd/fragments/FragmentBoxOffice.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try initializing the adapter. It's currently null.

```
myFormMainAdapter = new MyFormMainAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
viewPager.setAdapter(myFormMainAdapter);
```

Comment: now i have one more problem it only sorting data which loaded from sqlite it not work if we refresh the data